# How to use the Laplace distribution in a GLM model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, laplace-distribution

Good morning everyone!
I am a PhD student and I am performing some statistical analysis on a behavioral dataset related to aggression of pied flycatchers males against other male intruders. The aggression variables I am using are "males peck rate" (M_PECKS_H) and "males attack rate" (M_ATTACKS_H) and both have a Poisson distribution (I have tried transforming them to reach normality, but with no result). The research question I want to answer is: does the male's aggression depend on his ornamental traits? To answer this question, using the R software, I tried running GLM models with the aggression variable as the dependent variable, and the variables describing the male's ornaments as the independent variables (I performed a model for each aggression variable, so a total of two models). Performing some preliminary analysis, I realized that the two aggression variables (males peck rate and males attack rate) are highly correlated (B = 0.257, p<0.001), so it was suggested that I calculate the residuals of one variable for the other, and enter the residuals into the model as the dependent variable (I named the residual variable as "males physical aggression"). The problem is that this new variable is not normally distributed (I tried transforming it with common transformation methods, but to no avail). I used Statgraphics 19 software to figure out the closest distribution to its real distribution, and the result was "Laplace distribution."
So my final question is, how can I perform a GLM model having a variable with a Laplace distribution as the dependent variable?
I also add the three variables involved, if they can help with an answer
Thank you in advance to everyone who will answer me!

```
MALE.PHYSICAL.AGGRESSION
 [1]  0.32763821 -0.94806221  0.42966113 -0.40705296  1.64623753 -0.40606605 -1.69628970
 [8] -0.18288893 -0.24489983 -0.44856501 -0.36268715 -0.38924716  0.20351015 -0.40340094
[15] -0.24993494 -0.44856501 -0.13957284 -0.04492754 -0.44856501 -0.44856501  1.03867845
[22] -0.22239376  0.21517449 -0.29628075  0.35389341 -0.41711847  0.08461163 -0.09946749
[29] -0.44856501 -0.26643190 -0.44856501 -0.59306794 -0.07874262  0.65301432 -0.06027983
[36]  0.17872541  0.45812268  1.79260136 -0.38160072 -0.42591568  0.44959796 -0.22706765
[43]  0.23904110 -0.47172246 -0.33855633 -0.53399640  0.17416460  0.13808756 -0.38823318
[50] -0.08711228  1.30076077 -0.44856501 -0.44856501 -0.05768553  2.01970970  0.16219602
[57] -0.25543196 -0.16661012  0.52462825  2.55114656 -0.38777473  0.27825875 -0.10859473
[64] -0.29182520

M_ATTACKS_H
 [1] 1.04992280 0.72911392 1.27087576 0.05741627 3.12781955 0.09528851 4.18945312 0.29543420
 [9] 0.22116904 0.00000000 0.08587786 0.05931785 1.03394256 0.06246746 0.22338049 0.00000000
[17] 0.37368626 0.60900265 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.71682289 0.22617124 0.81407035 0.15228426
[25] 0.99122354 0.03144654 0.92912448 0.50713154 0.00000000 0.21638331 0.00000000 1.33806386
[33] 0.38772213 1.22320962 1.30573248 0.64516129 1.46143437 3.13621964 0.06696429 0.05078290
[41] 3.81947744 0.23797719 0.68760611 0.06015038 0.15215554 0.79107505 1.72962227 1.90779014
[49] 0.06033182 0.37894737 2.86294416 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.39087948 3.21804511 0.61076103
[57] 0.19313305 0.28195489 1.34604599 4.05882353 0.06079027 0.95642933 0.38980510 0.15673981

M_PECKS_H
 [1] 0.49408132 2.21772152 0.70875764 0.02870813 1.86466165 0.09528851 9.81445312 0.05371531
 [9] 0.03159558 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.68929504 0.03123373 0.04467610 0.00000000
[17] 0.11677696 0.37069726 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.41440552 0.00000000 0.27135678 0.00000000
[25] 0.34073309 0.00000000 0.71471114 0.28526149 0.00000000 0.06182380 0.00000000 2.67612772
[33] 0.03231018 0.21955044 1.65605095 0.03225807 1.00135318 1.61562830 0.00000000 0.05078290
[41] 5.27315915 0.02974715 0.00000000 0.15037594 0.07607777 1.58215010 1.99801193 2.38473768
[49] 0.00000000 0.03157895 2.01015228 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.35338346 0.00000000
[57] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.67302299 1.91176471 0.00000000 0.41445271 0.08995502 0.00000000
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us some plots? It seems what you have is a linear regression (with identity link function) model, which in R could be fitted with lm, you don´t need glm.  But that uses least squares, and if your errors are more closely approximated to a Laplace distribution, you should use absolute value as loss, not square! That can be fitted in R as "quantile regression", see the package quantreg.  But a different idea is: If your responses have a Poisson distribution, why not use Poisson regression?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What graphics would you like to see? 
Since the two dependent variables I used in two different models (M_ATTACK_H and M_PECK_H) are highly correlated, I calculated the residuals between these two variables to run a single model that has the residuals as the dependent variable. Therefore, I did not use a Poisson regression because the residuals I am using as the dependent variable do not follow a Poisson distribution.